# static buffer and non initialize static buffer

Tags: c

Hi i am having 2 questions here

1. How do i store a hex value in a buffer, say for example 0x0a and 0x1F;

   ```
   char buffer[2] = "0x0a 0x1F";
   ```

   But this is not right method, It is giving size 10 instead of 2. Can any one suggest how can i proceed.
2. I have seen the array like this

   ```
   char buffer[] = " static array";
   ```

   In the structure also,

   ```
   struct Point {
      char x[];
      char y[];
   };
   ```

   what does it mean? how much size it will take for compilation

Comment: `char buffer[2] = "\x0a\x1F";`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Did you mean `buffer[3]`?

Comment: @Andreas `buffer[2]` mean `buffer[2]`

Comment: Yes, but `"\x0a\x1F"` is three characters (remember the terminating `\0`)

Comment: @Andreas Use as an initialization constant long strings it is not an error in C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, was not aware of that -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915737/char-array-initialization-dilemma ; so, the `\0` is simply not stored (which makes this approach of initializing a buffer at least questionable, IMHO...)

Comment: @Andreas I understand that this is confusing, of course, but it was thought to be along the intention of the questioner.

Answer (score 5):

For the first, assuming you really want a two-byte array rather than a three-byte string (including NULL terminator), you can use:

```
char buffer[] = {0x0a, 0x1f};
```

For the second, the easiest way to find out is to simply check:

```
sizeof(buffer)
```

or:

```
sizeof(struct Point)
```

although I'm pretty certain your structure definition will fail because `char x[]` is not a complete type. Current versions of the standard allow flexible array sizes at the *end* of structures but not the way you have it there.

Likely sizes of the two (once you declare `struct Point` with `char x[5]`) will be 14 (number of characters in `" static array"` including the NULL terminator) and 5 (the size of `x` itself (flexible array members tend not to take up space, they're more for allowing arbitrary extra space if the memory block is obtained by `malloc`, for example).